# How can i get authorization token in rest API using rest assured?

Tags: rest-assured

In `postman` we can easily get the token and which can be use in `another` api `header` as `authorization`. How can I get authorization token in rest API using rest assured? Is it possible?

```json
{
  "status_code": 201,
  "status": "success",
  "results": {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImJpdGh5QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoiYml0aHlAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MywiZXhwIjoxNDkxODk2MjkwfQ.obAP1k8ObcyxLTHjQ3fP-9otvQAZNC0wM3TVoBXDEmE",
    "user_type": "employer"
  },
  "errors": null,
  "message_code": "sc_vw_user_login_1",
  "message": "Login successful."
}
```

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to above if you do also need to mention the grant_type along with simple credentials , you can use following example to achieve the same. Below example assumes you are using client_credentials grant_type. Also you may want to put this in @Before function of your Junit tests

```
String response =
            given().port(9090)
                .auth().basic("clientId", "secret")
                .basePath("/auth")
                .contentType("multipart/form-data")
                .multiPart("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .when()
                .post("/oauth/token")
                .asString();



    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response);
    accessToken = jsonPath.getString("access_token");
```

Answer (score -2):

As Olaia mentioned, you need to read documentation as to how to ask questions on stack overflow.

Anyways to answer your question, you can refer following steps

```
`String response =
            given()
                .parameters("username", username, "password", password)
                .auth()
                .preemptive()
            .when()
                .post("/oauth/token")
                .asString();

    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response);
    accessToken = jsonPath.getString("access_token");`
```

And then in the subsequent request you case pass the same accessToken in header

```
given()
        .auth().oauth2(accessToken)
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .accept(ContentType.JSON)
    .expect()...
```